# Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I would like to learn C# and using Visual Studio 2013. There are a few different flavors of Visual Studio Express 2013: for Web, for Windows and for Windows Desktop. I am not really sure which one I should download. Can someone advise on this? I borrowed the book Professional Visual Studio 2013 from the library, but it seems that this book is targeted for the professional version of Visual Studio 2013. Would I still be able to use the Express version to work on the examples in the book?

Also, I want to learn WPF, WCF and Silverlight, do they come bundled with the Web, Windows or Windows Desktop flavor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The download page gives an overview of what each version is for.  Web = web sites (and WCF), Windows = Win 8 Store Apps and Desktop = WinForms/WPF (in general terms).  There are some features of VS 2013 that aren't in the express editions and/or are present in one edition but not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download and install all 3 of the express edition since they are free and serve different purposes. However, I would suggest you to get a commercial version for many extra features and convenience.

Comment: Which of the 3 has WPF, WCF and Silverlight?

Comment: The Express Edition for Web has WCF and the Express Edition for Windows Desktop has WPF. You need to manually install silverlight as it doesn't come along with the express.